# Reallocating list in python

Tags: python, list, memory-management, collections

Ok this is my problem. I am trying something like this:

```
for i in big_list:
   del glist[:]

   for j in range(0:val)
         glist.append(blah[j])
```

The idea is to reset the list and reuse it for the next set of data points.
The problem is, for some reason, if the first list has 3 points,

```
glist[0]
glist[1]
glist[2]
```

The next list will continue from index 3 and store the last 3 elements in those indexes

```
glist[0] = 4th elem of new list
glist[1] = 5th elem of new list
glist[2] = 6th elem of new list
glist[3] = 1st elem of new list
glist[4] = 2nd elem of new list
glist[5] = 3rd elem of new list
```

I'm sure it is an issue with allocated space. But how can I achieve this del g_list[:] so the result is,

```
glist[0] = 1st elem of new list
glist[1] = 2nd elem of new list
glist[2] = 3rd elem of new list
glist[3] = 4th elem of new list
glist[4] = 5th elem of new list
glist[5] = 6th elem of new list
```

Allocating variable from within loop is not an option.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your code snippet makes very little sense.  Could you post code that's closer to what you're really trying to do.  big_list and val are undefined and i is never used.

Comment: "Allocating variable from within loop is not an option." - Could you give a summary of why you say this?  If it's for performance reasons, I think you should consider profiling before making the assumption that that will be faster.

Comment: The code in your example doens't have these effects, you need to replace them with your actual code.

But I suspect you are in fact modifying and looping over glist at the same time. That could have effects like that.

Comment: yeah it was something I was doing. I was using two lists and resetting only one... do'h ...is there any way to delete question

Comment: @grobartn: Close the question is approximately the same as deleting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `del glist[:]` to `glist = []`. You don't need to "reuse" or "reallocate" in Python, the garbagecollector will take care of that for you.

Also, you use 'i' as the loop variable in both loops. That's going to confuse you sooner or later. :)

Comment: i used that to begin with 
and then replaced it with del
but both did not work

Comment: I think he was paraphrasing his actual code, but I may be wrong +1 in any case

Comment: In fact, I seem to recall reading somewhere that it's actually faster to just destroy and reallocate the list than it is to try reallocating it.

Comment: @grobartn: You need to define "did not work".  Or provide an example.  It's best to either update your question or create a new question with your revised code.

Comment: That said, I don't actually get your error. Are you not in fact looping over glist as well? That would give this sorts of effects, I think.

Comment: I could not paste the actual code because it is copyrighted...this was just summary of the problem and had typo

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
glist=[]
```

Answer (score 1):

`del glist[:]` works fine for clearing a list.  You need to show us your exact code.  As shown below, the behavior you're describing does not happen.  The `append` after the `del a[:]` puts the item at index 0.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> del a[:]
>>> a
[]
>>> a.append(4)
>>> a
[4]
```